# The script is not assigning points to the attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a text-based adventure game and all is going well until I encountered a problem with assigning points to attributes.  [I've been using this website](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8285/character-creator-for-a-role-playing-game?newreg=9c4cbb3456eb446595623db81d616ec0) to help with the process but realized that it might be in Python 2. Here's all that I've done so far code:

```
#Date started: 3/13/2018
#Description: text-based adventure game

import random 
import time


def display_intro():
    print('It is the end of a 100-year war between good and evil that had \n' +
           'killed more than 80% of the total human population. \n')
    time.sleep(3)
    print('The man who will soon be your father was a brave adventurer who \n' +
           'fought for the good and was made famous for his heroism. \n')
    time.sleep(3)
    print('One day that brave adventurer meet a beautiful woman who he later \n' +
       'wed and had you. \n')
    time.sleep(3)


def get_gender(gen=None):
    while gen == None:  # input validation
        gen = input('\nYour mother had a [Boy or Girl]: ')
    return gen


def get_name(name = None):
    while name == None:
        name = input("\nAnd they named you: ")
    return name


def main():
    display_intro()
    gender_num = get_gender()
    charater_name = get_name()
    print("You entered {} {}.".format(gender_num, charater_name))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

character_name = get_name()

# Assignning points Main
my_character = {'name': character_name, 'strength': 0, 'wisdom': 0, 'dexterity': 0, 'points': 20}


#This is a sequence establises base stats.
def start_stat():
    print("\nThis is the most important part of the intro\n")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("This decides your future stats and potentially future gameplay.")
    time.sleep(4)
    print("\nYou have 20 points to put in any of the following category: 
Strength, Health, Wisdom, or Dexterity.\n")


def add_charater_points():   # This adds player points in the beginnning
    attribute = input("\nWhich attribute do you want to assign it to? ")
    if attribute in my_character.keys():
        amount = int(input("By how much?"))

        if (amount > my_character['points']) or (my_character['points'] <= 0):
            print("Not enough points!!! ")
        else:
            my_character[attribute] += amount
            my_character[attribute] -= amount
    else:
        print("That attribute doesn't exist!!!")


def print_character():
    for attribute in my_character.keys():
        print("{} : {}".format(attribute, my_character[attribute]))


playContinue = "no"
while playContinue == "no":
    Continue = input("Are you sure you want to continue?\n")
    if Continue == "yes" or "Yes" or "y":
        playContinue = "yes"
        start_stat()
        add_charater_points()
    else:
        display_intro()
        gender_num = get_gender()
        charater_name = get_name()

running = True

while running:
    print("\nYou have {} points left\n".format(my_character['points']))
    print("1. Add points\n2. Remove points. \n3. See current attributes. \n4. Exit\n")

    choice = input("Choice: ")

    if choice == "1":
        add_charater_points()
    elif choice == "2":
        pass
    elif choice == "3":
        print_character()
    elif choice == "4":
        running = False
    else:
        pass
```

And here's what happens when I run it:

```
It is the end of a 100-year war between good and evil that had 
killed more than 80% of the total human population. 

The man who will soon be your father was a brave adventurer who fought for 
the good and was made famous for his heroism. 

One day that brave adventurer meet a beautiful woman who he later wed and 
had you. 


Your mother had a [Boy or Girl]: boy

And they named you: Name
You entered boy Name.

And they named you: Name
Are you sure you want to continue?
yes

This is the most important part of the intro

This decides your future stats and potentially future gameplay.

You have 20 points to put in any of the following category: Strength, 
Health, Wisdom, or Dexterity.


Which attribute do you want to assign it to? strength
By how much? 20

You have 20 points left

1. Add points
2. Remove points. 
3. See current attributes. 
4. Exit

Choice: 3
name : Name
strength : 0
wisdom : 0
dexterity : 0
points : 20

You have 20 points left

1. Add points
2. Remove points. 
3. See current attributes. 
4. Exit

Choice:
```

Oh, and prompt for the name of the play goes again twice for some reason. Also, what does the `my_character.keys()` under `def add_charater_points()` mean? Since I just started to learn to code python, if there are any other tips you guys can give me it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two lines of this snippet

```
    if (amount > my_character['points']) or (my_character['points'] <= 0):
        print("Not enough points!!! ")
    else:
        my_character[attribute] += amount
        my_character[attribute] -= amount
```

add the character points to the attribute, *and immediately subtract them again*. I think you might mean

```
        my_character['points'] -= amount
```

Your repeated prompt is probably because you have a whole lot of code that logically seems to belong in function `main()` but is coded to run after `main()` finishes.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help!